# How to view the Create Table SQL command after a table has been created in mySQL phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, ddl, create-table

When you create a mySQL table using the GUI in phpAdmin there is an option to preview the SQL create table command.

Once you have created a table, made adjustments and finalised the structure, is it possible to review the SQL create command for the current version of the table?

Comment: [SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html)

Shows the CREATE TABLE statement that creates the named table. To use this statement, you must have some privilege for the table. This statement also works with views.

Answer (score 1):

While creating table there is PreviewSQL button:

[image]

You can always export table and see its SQL again or `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: how do I navigate to the view depicted in your answer ?